# R Is it possible to use vegan's ordisurf with a logarithmic scale

Tags: r, vegan

I'm using the ordisurf function to display the concentration of a certain substance within an NMDS plot. Unfortunately, the concentration ranges from 0.4 to 6 at the low end, including most of the samples. Only three samples are in the range from 500 to 1200: As you can see in the plot

[image: NMDS ordisurf plot]

the 3 samples "Mo7" are within the same ordisurf sections, whereas their Substance values are 1195.51, 615.95 and 553.27. The same goes for W22 samples, which values are close to 1.

Ordisurf here adds lines from 0 to 800, incrementing by 100. Would it be possible to use a logarithmic scale instead or somehow change the ordisurf plot parameters? This is my code

```
plot(nmds_cdna, type = "p", display = "sites", main ="title")
with(meta_data_cdna, ordisurf(nmds_cdna, sumSubstance, add = TRUE))
```

EDIT:
following Jari's suggestion I added the levels argument to the Ordisurf call. This solved the issues with the unprecise increments. Still, the ordisurf lines group samples not within the correct values. This is maybe the case when it is just not possible, e.g. the positioning within the NMDS and my Substance as only explanatory variable contradict each other?

```
plot(nmds_cdna, type = "p", display = "sites", main ="title")
with(meta_data_cdna, ordisurf(nmds_cdna, sumSubstance, add = TRUE, levels = c(0, 1 , 10, 500, 1200))
```

Comment: There's nothing stopping you modelling `log(sumSubstance)` or fitting a GAM and using a non-Gaussian family. You may need to combine this with `levels` or plot the surface in `log` space (i.e. draw contours at fitted values of `log(sumSubstance)`.

Comment: @gavonsimpson: thanks, I will have a look at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to ask whether `vegan::ordisurf()` has a `levels` argument to set the desired levels? If that was your question, the answer is positive: `vegan::ordisurf()` allows setting `levels`.

Comment: yes that is the parameter I was looking for...but as it turns out, the actual values and the ordisurf areas still do not fit. I played with other parameters here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/ordisurf but I can't get it to work

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "the actual values and the ordisurf areas still do not fit"?

Comment: if you check the 3 Mo7 samples in the plot (upper right corner). This samples have a sumSubstance value of 1195.51, 615.95 and 553.27 and are plotted within 500 and 700 (the same if I adjust `levels`). That is why I assume that the bray curtis dissimilary of the samples and the sumSubstance values may contradict each other (which is possible, of course). I'll try Gavin's suggestion, too.

Comment: `ordisurf` draws smooth **fitted** surfaces. If you want to interpolate noisy observed data, you need to use interpolation methods.